# How do I get the title I set through HtmlOutput's setTitle from the html side?

Tags: html, web, google-apps-script

I want to fetch the title I set using [setTitle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output?hl=en#settitletitle) method of HtmlOutput within the html source file, i.e., client-side, but it seems that calling `document.title` returns me empty string when I call it within my html file.

- Main.gs:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Build Form...', functionName: 'buildForm_'},
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Test', menuItems);
}

function buildForm_(){
  const reportTitle = "Some Title"
  const htmlForm = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Sidebar')
      .setTitle(reportTitle);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(htmlForm)
}
```

- HTML_Sidebar.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onmouseup="seeTitle()" id="seeTitleButton">See title</button>
  <script>
    function seeTitle() {
      document.getElementById("seeTitleButton").textContent = "(" + document.title + ")"
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Apps Script's documentation doesn't seem to specify a client-side method in the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html?hl=en) to query the title, and I was hoping that someone in the community could point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Do you mean the title of the Sidebar iframe?

Comment: Yes! What passes as `reportTitle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `<title>` is assigned to a outer iframe than the one your userAppCode lives in (userHtmlFrame) so when you call the `document` node you are reading from the iframe your app is contained in, which does not have the title.

A work around would be to use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) and store the title as a script property when setting it. And retrieving it from the properties when you want to use it. You still would need to use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to call a function on the server-side which would fetch  the title and return it to the client.

Comment: I think you are right. The title is held in `script-application-sidebar-title` div in the DOM, and it is a cross-origin access to the title element from the iframe (which should not be possible).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getTitle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#gettitle):

> Gets the title of the output page. Note that the `<title>` HTML element is ignored.

```
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
Logger.log(output.getTitle());
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#gettitle

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sure this works in the .gs files, but I'm not sure how to call `getTitle` from the .html file in the project. Note that, `var output` above only gets created on the server-side.

Comment: @madarez that must be Apps Script bug, see related issue reported at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77964642 You can "star" it, or fill new one describing your use case.